# Mvc Caching muiltple version of the same partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have five buttons on a page.  Each one triggers the same action but with different parameters.  In turn, the same partial view is return but with different data.
When the partial view is returned I append it to a div, but I clear the div so only the current button's partial view is displayed.
I would like to cache the changes made to a partial view so users can click from one button to the next without have losing there data on any of the partial views.

Comment: Add html and js, at least a part

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the content on the single div, you may keep 5 different div's, one for each button's data and show only one at a time ( the one which is associated with the button which was clicked).

Since you are simply hiding it, You won't lose any form data user entered until they reload the page.

Quick sample.

I will create 3 buttons and 3 details views (one for each button). I am using html 5 data attribute to define the association between the buttons and the details view div ( `data-details-view` property)

```
<div id="btnContainer">
    <button type="button" class="item-btn" data-val="1" data-details-view="details-1">Form 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="item-btn" data-val="2" data-details-view="details-2">Form 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="item-btn" data-val="3" data-details-view="details-3">Form 3</button>
</div>

<!-- Now we will have details pane for each form -->
<div>
    <div class="item-details" id="details-1" data-view-loaded="false"></div>
    <div class="item-details" id="details-2" data-view-loaded="false"></div>
    <div class="item-details" id="details-3" data-view-loaded="false"></div>
</div>
```

Now have some javascript to listen to the click even on the button, Read the Id (or any other property you are interested in ), Make the call to get your partial view, Set the details view markup with the partial view result received.

I am using data-view-loaded property to determine whether to reload the partial view again when user clicks on the button for a second time,

```
$(function() {

    $("button.item-btn").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedBtn = $(this);

        //Hide all the details views.

        $(".item-details").hide();

        var targetDivId = clickedBtn.data("details-view");
        var loadedAlready = $("#" + targetDivId).data("view-loaded");
        if(!loadedAlready)
        {
            //Assuming urlToPartialView contains the url to your partial view and the 
           // endpoint accepts an id value. you can change this anyway you want

            var url = urlToPartialView+ clickedBtn.data("val");

            alert(url);

            $.get(url, function(res) {

                $("#" + targetDivId).html(res).data("view-loaded",true);
            });
        }
        //Show detail view for only the clicked one.
        $("#" + targetDivId).show();
    });

});
```